# destruction of std::stringbuf causing access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, buffer, access-violation

I have a c++ class that roughly looks like this (see code below). It has an input buffer and an output buffer using a std::stringbuf. Because I also want access to the raw buffer, I set the underlying buffer with my own user-defined byte array using std::stringbuf.pubsetbuf().

All things seem to work fine, until I no longer need the object but when the object is destructed, it causes my program to crash with an access violation.

I traced it down to the piece of code as illustrated below. It looks to me that the stringbuf is somehow cleaning up my user-defined byte array itself?? My program doesn't crash when I remove the code in the destrcutor of my class to free the byte array I previously allocated in the constructor.

Any advice on this, please? Am I wrongly using the std::stringbuf? I'm using the Borland 5.0 compiler (I know it's a very old and outdated compiler, but I have to stick to this compiler for a while).

```
class SomeClass {

private:

    char *mIBuf;
    char *mOBuf;

    std::stringbuf mIBufStream;
    std::stringbuf mOBufStream;

public:

    SomeClass(int iBufSize, int oBufSize) :
      mIBuf(), mOBuf(),
      mIBufStream(), mOBufStream()
    {
        mIBuf = (char*)malloc(iBufSize);
        mOBuf = (char*)malloc(oBufSize);

        mIBufStream.pubsetbuf(mIBuf, iBufSize);
        mIBufStream.pubseekpos(0);

        mOBufStream.pubsetbuf(mOBuf, oBufSize);
        mOBufStream.pubseekpos(0);
    }

    virtual ~SomeClass()
    {
        free(mIBuf);
        free(mOBuf)
    }

};
```

Comment: The Standard says that `stringbuf::setbuf` (which is what `pubsetbuf` calls) has implementation-defined behavior.  Do you happen to have the documentation for your specific implementation?

Comment: Also, it looks like you didn't paste your actual code but retyped it?  And weren't very careful about punctuation in the process.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yup, the code tags misalignment threw me :) ... redacted comment

Comment: @BenVoight: yes indeed, I retyped my code because I wanted to have the sample code look as clean as possible for reading here. Wasn't too careful about the punctuations. Sorry for that. I have corrected the punctuation.

I don't have documentation for my specific implementation. Maybe I can find it somewhere, but right now I have no clue where I could find that.

Comment: The destructor of the base class `std::streambuf` takes care of the deletion of the pointers.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I hope not.  When a `stringbuf` is first created, it is using a buffer managed by a `std::string`.  If `streambuf` attempts to delete that buffer...  Besides, the Standard says that `basic_streambuf<T>::~basic_streambuf()` has no effects

Comment: @0x499602D2: So, I should remove my code in the constructor? I can do this without worrying about a memory leak. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Standard `stringbuf` doesn't have a destructor of its own and `streambuf`'s destructor does nothing.  Your old compiler and library may or may not be following that; the evidence is that it isn't.

Well, in principle you are doing something wrong.  When you call `pubsetbuf` you are giving that object permission to use that buffer for as long as the object lives, or until you change its buffer again.

Looking at your destructor, you aren't keeping your side of the bargain.

```
virtual ~SomeClass()
{
    free(mIBuf);
    free(mOBuf); // <- missing semicolon in your code

    // the stringbuf objects are still alive here
}   // they get automatically destroyed here
```

One option is to arrange for the `stringbuf` objects to be destroyed before you free the buffers (`char*` buffer deallocation will need to be done by a helper class, either a base class or a member declared before the `stringbuf` -- `std::vector<char>` would be a good choice).

Or, you can let the `stringbuf` know that you're revoking its permission to use your memory:

```
virtual ~SomeClass()
{
    mIBufStream.pubsetbuf(0, 0);
    mOBufStream.pubsetbuf(0, 0);

    // the stringbufs cannot use your memory any longer

    free(mIBuf);
    free(mOBuf);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I already tried what you have suggested. I was using a std::vector<char> before instead of the char* buffer (but to isolate the cause of my issue, I replaced that piece of code). Revoking the permission ont the std::stringbuf with the pubsetbuf(0, 0) doesn't seem to solve my issue (at least not with the compiler and library I'm using).

So, I suspect my Borland stl library may not be following the standard.

Comment: @cpirate: If you're seeing crashes even after you change the buffer again, I suspect there is some memory corruption going on causing your call to `free` to fail, not actually any attempt by `stringbuf` to use or free the buffer during destruction.

Comment: @BenVoight: Hi, I have further tested this sample code. I extracted this class and put it in a small test program. No other code that might possibly corrupt the program. One version compiled with Visual Studio 2013, the other compiled with Borland 5.0. Visual studio seems to execute the program without crash, there where Borland crashes it.

So, I'm quite certain by now that it's the Borland stl library implementation not being conform the standard implementation. I suspect that the std::stringbuf.pubsetbuf() in the Borland version just does nothing when I pass 0 as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer my own question... (and thanks to Ben Voight for his useful advise). Until someone else would prove me wrong, I've come to the conclusion that my issue is implementation specific and that the Borland 5.0 STL library may not be conform the standard.

I tested my sample class. I extracted it and put it in a small test program as listed below (no other code that would possibly corrupt the memory). I compiled 1 version with Visual Studio 2013, the other with Borland 5.0. The one compiled with Visual Studio runs just fine. The one compiled with Borland crashes after the 1st iteration.

```
#include <iostream>
```

## include

class SomeClass {

```
char *mIBuf;
char *mOBuf;

std::stringbuf mIBufStream;
std::stringbuf mOBufStream;
```

public:

```
SomeClass(int iBufSize, int oBufSize) : mIBuf(NULL), mOBuf(NULL), mIBufStream(), mOBufStream() {
    mIBuf = (char*)malloc(iBufSize);
    mOBuf = (char*)malloc(oBufSize);

    mIBufStream.pubsetbuf(mIBuf, iBufSize);
    mIBufStream.pubseekpos(0);

    mOBufStream.pubsetbuf(mOBuf, oBufSize);
    mOBufStream.pubseekpos(0);
}

virtual ~SomeClass() {
    mIBufStream.pubsetbuf(0, 0);
    mOBufStream.pubsetbuf(0, 0);

    free(mIBuf);
    free(mOBuf);
}
```

};

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
        SomeClass SomeClass(128 * 1024, 128 * 1024);
        std::cout << "Pass " << x + 1 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```